# Solution of the parabolic equation $u_t=(axu)_{xx}-((bx+c)u)_x$

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

I am reading a book and it says that the  Kolmogorov equation is similar to the parabolic equation $$u_t=(axu)_{xx}-((bx+c)u)_x$$ 
This may seem like a silly question but how is this a parabolic equation?
Also 
If $$c\leq0$$ and/or $$0<c<a$$ why does this parabola equation have a unique solution?

Comment: It is not a parabola, it is a parabolic equation.

Comment: equations of the form $u_t = ku_xx + bu_x + cu$ are called parabolic partial differential equation. in your example, the constant $k$ depends on $x.$

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just like conic sections can be parabolic or hyperbolic (think back to 3-D calculus), so can partial differential equations. The classification scheme is actually quite similar too. Recall an equation is parabolic if its something like $c = x^2 + x$ (you can complete the square to make it look nicer)

This classification structure extends to pdes, since your primary (spatial) derivative is $u_{xx}$ this provides the classification of parabolic

Comment: How would you go about solving the parabolic equation in the question? Is it something to do with laplace transforms?